# Equivalence relations confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying Abstract Algebra and am wondering about the definition of an equivalence relation. There seem to be two definitions I was hearing: if the relation is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive then it is an equivalence relation. The other definition was that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then an equivalence relation is iff for $x,y \in H$ $x = yh$ for some $h \in H$. This almost makes sense to me, and I am just a little confused on the second definition. Does that mean for *any* $x,y \in G$ $x = yh$ for some fixed $h \in H$ or that for some $x,y \in G$ $x = yh$ for any $h \in G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition you've heard is indeed "the" definition, the second definition, is a definition of a *particular* equivalence relation on a particular kind of set, a group $G$ (with a binary group operation), and a subgroup $H$.

The particular relation is called "congruence modulo $H$", or as one sometimes finds in the literature, that $x$ is a *translate* of $y$ via $H$.

If $G$ is non-abelian, there are actually two versions of this, a left version, and a right version. What you have is the "left version" since the non-$H$ elements are multiplied on the left side.

Although one can make the *definition* as angryavian does above, that $x \sim y$ if and only if there is some $h \in H$ with $x = yh$, it is not immediately evident that this is, in fact, an example of an equivalence relation. One has to demonstrate this, which I shall do:

1. (Left) congruence modulo $H$ is reflexive:

Since $H$ is a subgroup, $e_G \in H$, and $x = xe_G$, so we can pick $h = e_G$ to see that $x \sim x$.

2. (Left) congruence modulo $H$ is symmetric.

If we have $x = yh$ (that is $x \sim y$) for some $h$, then $y = ye_G = y(hh^{-1}) = (yh)h^{-1} = xh^{-1}$. Since $H$ is a subgroup, $h^{-1}$ is in $H$ whenever $h$ is, and can serve as our element of $H$ that relates $y$ to $x$, so $y \sim x$.

3. (Left) congruence modulo $H$ is transitive.

Suppose $x \sim y$, and $y \sim z$. That is, $x = yh$, and $y = zh'$, for some $h,h' \in H$.

Then $x = yh = (zh')h = z(h'h)$ and $h'h \in H$ by the closure of $H$ under multiplication (since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$). Hence $x \sim z$.

---

Although we can do this for any subgroup $H$ of any subgroup $G$, it turns out the subgroups $H$ for which the left and right versions of congruence modulo $H$ agree, are *special*, because these "subdivisions" (partitions) of $G$ respect the group operation, allowing us to multiply entire equivalence classes as if they were single entities.

---

Note: to answer your second question, yes, $x$ and $y$ might be any two group elements...BUT! Only certain pairs will be related (via $H$).

Comment: What do you mean by (Left) when you say (Left) congruence modulo $H$?

Comment: There is another possible equivalence relation: $x \sim y$ if and only if $x = hy$. The equivalence class in this case is $Hx = \{hx|h \in H\}$, which is known as a right-coset of $H$, whereas the equivalence classes we consider above are left-cosets of $H$, such as $xH = \{xh|h \in H\}$. Often, these are different.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence relation is "two arbitrary elements $x$ and $y$ of $G$ are *related* (often denoted $x \sim y$) if and only if there exists some $h \in H$ such that $x=yh$." The equivalence classes in this case are known as [cosets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset#Definition_using_equivalence_classes).